# Kafka generate ssl .sh file get stuck

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I have [**this confluent security bash file**](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-platform-security-tools/blob/master/kafka-generate-ssl.sh) through which I want to generate keystore, but the problem is it get stuck at this stage:

[image].

I just simply run the .sh file using git bash.

I found that the next line after it

```
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout $TRUSTSTORE_WORKING_DIRECTORY/ca-key \
    -out $TRUSTSTORE_WORKING_DIRECTORY/ca-cert -days $VALIDITY_IN_DAYS
```

Then, I checked `openssl` is rightly configure in environment variable. I don't know why it has stuck here.

Comment: Instead of posting images, can you share the exact command and the full output you get?

Comment: Yeah i have posted the full code. here is the link (https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-platform-security-tools/blob/master/kafka-generate-ssl.sh) and just simply run it by double clicking the .sh file. It is running through git bash directly.

Comment: Those commands werent tested in a windows environment, fwiw. Why not use WSL or Puttygen?